# How to capture 360 images in a React Native App?

Tags: react-native, camera, react-native-camera, 360-degrees, 360-panorama

I need to implement the functionality to capture 360 panoramic images in my React Native App. So far I have not found any library or method to implement this. What is the best method to implement this functionality in React Native? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first, implement in platform Android and IOS.

secend, you can implement a [Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro) or [Native UI Components](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).